# Exercise about the fundamental group of $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, projective-geometry, projective-space, fundamental-groups

Let $p$ be a point in $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\Sigma$ the set containing all the projective lines passing through $p$. Given $s\in \Sigma$ we can define a continuous closed path (let's say $\Omega(\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R}),p,p)$ are all continuous paths starting and ending in $p$). The exercize asks is any two lines $s_1,s_2\in \Omega(\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R}),p,p)$ are homotopic which should be true since we can take a projectivity that maps $s_1$ into $s_2$.

But then it asks to use that fact to prove that $s\in  \Omega(\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R}),p,p)$ generates the fundamental group of  $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$.

This seems strange to me since the fundamental group of  $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $s$ i homeomorphic to a circle.

Can you help me? 
Thank you!

Comment: $\Bbb RP^n$ is double covered by $S^n$ in the obvious way. For $n>1$ this is the universal cover. If you want to show a closed generates the fundamental group (the fundamental group is defined as being equivalence classes of closed paths), you just check that this closed path lifts to a non-closed path in the universal cover. Saying that, this is basically unreadable and you have given no hint to what $s$ is being defined as...

Answer (score 0):

If you already know that the fundamental group is $\mathbb Z_2$ then there is little to prove except that the homotopy class of $s$ is nontrivial, i.e., that a projective line cannot be continuously contracted to a point.

On the other hand the whole point of the exercise seems to be to prove that all closed curves are homotopic to either a point or a projective line, so it seems to me that the assumption $\pi_1=\mathbb Z_2$ is not supposed to be a given.

Finally, the fact that $s$ is homeomorphic to a circle should not be too surprising - the whole definition of the fundamental group of *any* space depends on homotopy-equivalence classes of closed paths, i.e., homeomorphic images of the circle. Recall that the group operation of $\pi_1$ is defined by glueing together two closed paths, so "generated by" should be interpreted in these terms.